# Merchant of Venice can't buy a City State

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I have a Merchant of Venice, I have moved next to a city state, but the only option I'm given is a trade mission. It has trade mission bonuses, but I'd really like a puppet. I've seen a video where the Merchant has an action icon that looks like a trade mission, but has a gold coin on top of it, but I only see the Mission/Move/Do Nothing/Sleep/Embark/extra actions, and the only extra is delete the unit.

The city state is allied and under protection of Greece, but I haven't read about that as a restriction.

Other Venice stuff is working - 2*trade routes, free Merchant, trade mission bonus, and no settlers allowed.

I've never played Venice before, so I'm not sure if there a rule I'm missing or if it is a bug.

I am playing Steam version BNW on a Mac - in case that makes any difference.

Comment: Well, _I wonder if I accidentally clicked on One City Challenge - how do I check that?_ - a possible option is to go and capture another civ's city.

Comment: Don't edit more questions into your post. "How do I check if one-city challenge is enabled" should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: @SergiiZaskaleta Thanks. Did that, and it said I captured the city, but the city info disappeared while keeping the city graphics on the map. The OCC was set as a persistent option from a previous player's game. I started a second game with no special options which also malfunctioned. I needed to find the option and unset it for the next game to work.

Answer (score 3):

The game was set to One City Challenge, but I had not set it to One City Challenge. I know because I restarted another game being careful to do no special options (just Venice), but it still ran a One City Challenge Game.

A previous player had gone into a sub-sub menu (Advanced Setup >> Advanced Game Options) in Set Up Game, and set to One City Challenge. When I did subsequent games with Set Up Game, it kept all of the previous settings, including all the 'hidden' Advanced Game Options.

It seems like a fairly major option to keep persistent in a sub-sub menu! I would consider this a UI bug.

Comment: Keep in mind that most players like their game in a certain way, and will 9 times out of 10 prefer to have all their games to have the same specific settings. E.g. I love playing with random personalities, and turn on quick combat. I never turn those options off and it'd be a hassle to do it every time I start a game.

Answer (score -1):

You have to be allies with the city state in order to buy them out. You must remain allies with the city state for 10 turns or you can't buy them

Comment: This is not correct.  You may be thinking of Austria.

Comment: Am I? Oh....whoops! Silly me!

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I checked that but Kyralessa is right about it being Austria

Comment: @Richard thank you for confirming what he/she said. I tried at least